# What does 부르노니 mean?

Tags: conjugation, suffix

So I started watching 백설 공주와 일곱 난쟁이 and the Evil Queen says to the magic mirror:

> 캄캄한 어둠과 바람 속에서 내 너를 부르노니 나와 대답하여라.

I'm trying to figure out exactly what is happening with '부르노니'. I understand that the whole phrase means something like 'I have called out to you in the pitch-black darkness and wind, so answer me.' But I don't understand exactly what purpose the '노니' in '부르노니' serves. I'm aware that '~니' typically signifies a cause or a reason (like if it were just '부르니') so I imagine that's what it's doing here, but that still doesn't explain this '노'. I doubt it is the same '~노' that appears in questions, and I'm tempted to assume it's simply an archaic verb form used for dramatic effect, but that also seems dubious at best. Perhaps it could be a typo, but I also doubt this.

Sorry for the incoherent jumble of theories. I'm just completely stumped lol. If anyone knows what this '노니' is doing, I'd be grateful for an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the even more ancient way of saying 느니라, which itself is already archaic. 느니라 according to the 표준국어대사전 and 고려대한국어대사전 respectively:

> (예스러운 표현으로) ***해라***할 자리에 쓰여, ***진리***나 으레 있는 사실을 가르쳐 줌을 나타내는 종결 어미

> 동사나 ‘있다’, ‘없다’의 어간 또는 선어말 어미 ‘-으시-’, ‘-었-’, ‘-겠-’의 뒤에 붙어, ***당연하게 여길 만한 사실을 단정적으로 가르쳐 줌을 나타내는 말***. 해라체로, 주로 옛 말투에 쓰인다

That is to say, it's the stronger way of saying 'go do something' or **해라**, and it's used to express the whole truth and nothing but the truth. It is ABSOLUTE. And because it's so absolute, it's used to address an 아랫사람 (someone of lower caste) by a 윗사람 (someone of higher caste) as a means of command, or even just plain speech/narrative.

> Example as a command: 널 부르느니라/널 부르노니라! I call upon thee!

> Example as a narrative: 아주 많이 먹었느니라/아주 많이 먹었노니라. I had a terrific meal, e.g. said by a king to his cook.